# How can I go back and forth between modules in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a Home Screen for two games in pygame, I changed the first game's name to module1 in the code Im providing and the Home Screen to Mainscreen

module1 is already done and now I'm just trying to get the Main Menu script to import the maingame when I click on the play button that I already have on the screen display, then when I finish the game (health reaches 0) , if I want to go back to the Main Menu I should just click anywhere on the "game over" screen that should appear when health reaches 0 or press escape.

here is what I tried:

this is the whole game script, the game loop is at the end of the script and sorry for how messy it is:

```
# Pygame skeleton

import pygame
import math
import random
import sys
import os

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

# Constants

WIDTH = 1306
HEIGHT = 526 
FPS_INGAME = 60
FPS_HOMESCREEN = 30
FULL_SCREEN = (0,0)

bullet_img = pygame.image.load('Bullet.png')

jump = False

bullet_timer = 0
score = 0

moving_left = False
moving_right = False
shoot = False
acceleration = 0.7
friction = -0.1
gravity = 9.8
platform_color = (150,59,230)

# Classes and Sprites


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.shoot_cooldown = 0
        self.anime = []
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.action = 0
        animation_types = ["Shoot","Go"]
        for animation in animation_types:
            temp_list = []

            num_of_frames = len(os.listdir(f'MySprite/{animation}'))
            for i in range(1,num_of_frames):
                img = pygame.image.load(f'MySprite/{animation}/{i}.png')
                temp_list.append(img)
            self.anime.append(temp_list)


        self.direction = 1
        self.flip = False 
        

        self.image = self.anime[self.action][self.frame_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        

        # vectors and sprite constants
        
        self.health = 100
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
        self.vel_vec = vec(0,0)
        self.acc_vec = vec(0,0)


    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y += 1
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player_group.sprite, platform_group,False)
        self.rect.y -= -1
        if hits:
            self.vel_vec.y = -15

    def screen_edge(self):
        if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
            self.pos.x = 0
        if self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = WIDTH

    def get_damage(self,damage_mag):
        self.health -= damage_mag

    def update(self):

        animation_cooldown = 75
        self.image = self.anime[self.action][self.frame_index]
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.update_time >= animation_cooldown:
            self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.frame_index += 1
        if self.frame_index >= len(self.anime[self.action]):
            self.frame_index = 0

        if self.shoot_cooldown > 0:
            self.shoot_cooldown -= 1

    def update_action(self,new_action):
        if new_action != self.action:
            self.action = new_action
            self.frame_index = 0
            self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def move(self,moving_left,moving_right):
        self.acc_vec = vec(0,acceleration)
        if moving_left:
            self.acc_vec.x = -(acceleration)
            self.direction = 1
            self.flip = False

        if moving_right:
            self.acc_vec.x = acceleration
            self.direction = -1
            self.flip = True

        self.acc_vec.x += self.vel_vec.x * friction
        self.vel_vec += self.acc_vec
        self.pos += self.vel_vec + 0.5 * self.acc_vec
        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player_group.sprite, platform_group,False)
        if hits:
            self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
            self.vel_vec.y = 0

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.image,self.flip,False),self.rect)
 

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
            super().__init__()
            self.image = pygame.Surface((w,h))
            self.image.fill(platform_color)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.x = x
            self.rect.y = y


class Hostiles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x_pos,y_pos,speed):
        super(Hostiles,self).__init__()

        self.images = []
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_2.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_5.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_6.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_7.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_8.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_9.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images/go_10.png'))
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x_pos,y_pos))
        self.speed = speed

    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect.centerx += self.speed
        if self.rect.centerx >= 1350 or self.rect.centerx <= -50:
            self.kill()

class Hostiles2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x_pos,y_pos,speed):
        super(Hostiles2,self).__init__()

        self.images2 = []
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_1.png'))
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_2.png'))
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_3.png'))
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_4.png'))
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_5.png'))
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_6.png'))
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_7.png'))
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_8.png'))
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_9.png'))
        self.images2.append(pygame.image.load('MySprite/images2/go_10.png'))
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images2[self.index]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x_pos,y_pos))
        self.speed = speed

    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images2):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images2[self.index]
        self.rect.centerx += self.speed
        if self.rect.centerx >= 1350 or self.rect.centerx <= -50:
            self.kill()

class Bullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,direction):
        super().__init__()
        self.speed = 10
        self.image = bullet_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x,y))
        self.direction = direction

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x -= (self.direction * self.speed)

        if self.rect.left >= WIDTH or self.rect.right <= 0:  
            self.kill()

        screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)

# Functions

def make_text(font_type,font_size,text,color,position):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_type, font_size)
    title = font.render(text,True,(color))
    title_rect = title.get_rect(center = (position))
    screen.blit(title,title_rect)

def main_game():
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(22,20,200,10))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,platform_color,(22,20,2 * player_group.sprite.health,10))
    screen.blit(heart,(0,2))

    bullet_group.draw(screen)  
    player.draw() 
    hostiles_group.draw(screen)
    platform_group.draw(screen)

    bullet_group.update()
    player_group.update()
    hostiles_group.update()
    player_group.update()

    player.screen_edge()
    
    if shoot:
        if player.shoot_cooldown == 0:

            bullet = Bullets(player.rect.centerx - (0.6 * player.direction * player.rect.size[0]),player.rect.centery,player.direction)
            bullet_group.add(bullet)
            player.shoot_cooldown = 40

    if moving_left or moving_right:
        player.update_action(1)

    else:
        player.update_action(0)
    player.move(moving_left,moving_right)


    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player_group.sprite,hostiles_group,True):
        player_group.sprite.get_damage(10)



    pygame.sprite.groupcollide(hostiles_group, bullet_group,True,True)
    return 2

def game_over():
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    text = gamefont.render("GAME OVER",True,(255,255,255))
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center = (653,243))
    screen.blit(text,text_rect)

    scoresurface = gamefont.render(f"Score: {score}",True,(255,255,255))
    score_rect = scoresurface.get_rect(center = (653,283))
    screen.blit(scoresurface,score_rect)

# Creating window

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("game name")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Groups and objects

gamefont = pygame.font.Font('Chernobyl.ttf',40)

player = Player()


platform = Platform(0,HEIGHT-96,WIDTH,100)

platform_group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
platform_group.add(platform)

player_group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
player_group.add(player)

hostiles_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
hostile_event = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(hostile_event,300)


bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

sky = pygame.image.load('SkyNight.png')
wallpaper = pygame.image.load('GamePlatform.png')
heart = pygame.image.load('Heart.png')

# Game loop

running = True
while running:
    # Events (Inputs)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
        if event.type == hostile_event:
            random_xpos = [-40,-20]
            random_xpos2 = [1340,1360]
            random_hs = [-2,2]
            hostile_left = Hostiles2(random.choice(random_xpos),400,random.choice(random_hs))
            hostile_right = Hostiles(random.choice(random_xpos2),400,random.choice(random_hs))
            hostiles_group.add(hostile_left,hostile_right)
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and player_group.sprite.health <= 0:
            player_group.sprite.health = 100
            hostiles_group.empty()
            score  = 0
            import MainMenu

        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                shoot = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                moving_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                shoot = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player_group.sprite.jump()



    if player_group.sprite.health > 0:
        score += main_game()
        print (score)
    else:
        game_over()

    pygame.display.update()
    screen.blit(sky,FULL_SCREEN)
    screen.blit(wallpaper,FULL_SCREEN)
    programIcon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
    pygame.display.set_icon(programIcon)
    clock.tick(FPS_INGAME)
```

and this is all the main screen / main menu .py file:

```
import pygame,sys
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1306,526))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
screen_home = pygame.image.load('HomeScreen.png')

def make_text(font_type,font_size,text,color,position):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_type, font_size)
    title = font.render(text,True,(color))
    title_rect = title.get_rect(center = (position))
    screen.blit(title,title_rect)



while True:
    
    font1 = pygame.font.Font('Starjedi.ttf',60)
    game1 = font1.render("Play",True,(255,255,255))
    game1_rect = game1.get_rect(center = (640,300))
   
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if game1_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                import MainGame.py

    screen.blit(screen_home,(0,0))
    screen.blit(game1,game1_rect)
    make_text('Chernobyl.ttf',70,"Title Here",(255,255,255),(315,80))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(45)
```

when I run the main menu I get the Home Screen I made, then I click on the on my display screen and it imports the game script and the game starts, when my health reaches 0 and I click on the screen to quit the game loop, it takes me back to the main menu which is exactly what I wanted,however, when I press play again to go back to the game it doesn't work it gives me an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MainGame.py'; 'MainGame' is not a package
```

I know the code is a mess I'm still new at this I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear enough, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is too little code to know what the problem is. It would be better if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that I see your code I can see you have a big problem using `import`:

You use it like this:

```
import MainGame.py
```

Assume the file you created is `MainGame.py` you supposed to import it this way:

```
import MainGame
```

Same goes to

```
import MainMenu.py
```

And that's might be the problem, though if you still have an issue, so instead of:

> in the game, this is part of the main game loop:

Please copy **all** of the code, in both files, and write the name of each file next to the code.

Comment: I imported the modules inside an if block because I want the main screen module to open if i press escape/quit and I want the game to open if I press a button on the main screen page, ill try editing the question with more code for better clarification

Comment: I saw your edit and I edited my answer as well.

Comment: it fixed the error but it doesn't do anything after I press play for the second time, nothing at all, I uploaded the whole code to my question, thanks a lot for your time I really appreciate it.